# How to change font size and text color in a transition slide in ioslides rmarkdown

Tags: css, r-markdown, ioslides

I want to change the font size and text color in a transition slide in ioslides rmarkdown using a css file.

I am creating a transition slide with only one number sign #

"#" Section I

Note: the number sign in my rmarkdown files is without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The single-hash slides are `slide.dark` and the main font of these slides is the `h2` group, so you need something like this in your `.css`:

```
slides > slide.dark > hgroup h2 {
  color: #FFFFBB;
  font-size: 72px;
  letter-spacing: 10;
}
```

Other elements of this slide like `background` can be customized with

```
slides > slide.dark {
  background: none !important;
  background-color: #444444 !important;
}
```